# Can I get the whole word against which the regex matched

Tags: scala

In the following code, is there a way to get the whole string `hello` instead of `Some(h)`. I want to get the word/string for which the regex matched.

```
scala> val reg = "h".r
reg: scala.util.matching.Regex = h

scala> reg findFirstIn "hello handsome"
res48: Option[String] = Some(h)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to capture the word starting with `h` you have to change the regex. Something like this,

```
  scala> val reg = """h\w+""".r
  reg: scala.util.matching.Regex = h\w+

  scala> reg findFirstIn "hello handsome"
  res4: Option[String] = Some(hello)

  scala> reg findFirstIn "random handsome"
  res5: Option[String] = Some(handsome)

  scala> reg findFirstIn "random person"
  res6: Option[String] = None
```

In above regex `h\w+` captures the word starting with `h`.